# Convert roman from \thepage into arabic

Tags: etoolbox, arabic, roman

I am having trouble getting the value from \thepage (which is in roman style) and converting it to arabic to set some counter.

A very simple example of what I want to do is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    
    \thepage
    
    \rmntonum{\thepage}
\end{document}
```

And I get

[image]

I would want to see:

```
i
1
```

Comment: `\arabic{page}`, as mico suggests, is the easiest.  But if you want to go the `\rmntonum` route, for whatever reason, then use `\expanded{\noexpand\rmntonum{\thepage}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display the value of the `page` counter using arabic numerals, use `\arabic{page}`. To set the value of some other counter to the page number, use `\value{page}`.

Comment: Simple and fast! Thank you